# ASP.NET Core post data not serealize custom field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and angular.

I send a post request from the object model to the controller method.

[image]

The controller method accepts an object at the input, but the bindingParameters field is empty.

[image]

The bindingParameters field is a list of KeyValueItem objects.

**TmObject.cs**

```
namespace v1.Atm
{
    public class TmObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("binding")]
        public string Binding { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sourceBindingParameters")]
        public string SourceBindingParameters { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonProperty("bindingParameters")]
        public List<TmKeyValueItem> BindingParameters
        {
            get
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TmKeyValueItem>>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceBindingParameters) ? "" : SourceBindingParameters);
            }
            set
            {
                SourceBindingParameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("caption")]
        public string Caption { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string SourceParameterGroups { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonProperty("parameterGroups")]
        public List<string> ParameterGroups
        {
            get
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceParameterGroups) ? "" : SourceParameterGroups);
            }
            set
            {
                SourceParameterGroups = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonProperty("parameters")]
        public List<TmObjectParameter> Parameters;

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonProperty("removeParameters")]
        public List<int> RemoveParameters { get; set; }

        public TmObject()
        {
            Parameters = new List<TmObjectParameter>();
            RemoveParameters = new List<int>();
        }
    }
}
```

If the bindingParameters field is changed, it works:

```
[NotMapped]
[JsonProperty("bindingParameters")]
public List<BindingParameter> BindingParameters{ get; set; }
```

Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

P.S. Prior to this, the project was implemented on ASP.NET Webforms and there the code described above worked.

**update**

I got out of the problem as follows. Opened the SourceBindingParameters field for visibility on the client by adding [JsonProperty ("sourceBindingParameters")]. And before sending data to the server, I serialize the values from BindingParameters to sourceBindingParameters.

```
  public updateTmObject(tmObject: TmObject) {
    tmObject.sourceBindingParameters = JSON.stringify(tmObject.bindingParameters);  

    return this.httpService.post('/v1/Editor/UpdateObject', JSON.stringify(tmObject.bindingParameters), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.reset();
        this.getTmObjects();
        return true;
      },
      error => {
        console.error("TmObjects|TmObjectsService.updateTmObject(): " + error.status);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bindingParameters` from request is not a list of `string` values but complex objects. You'd better create a class for this objects

```
public class BindingParameter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

and declare the property as the following

```
public List<BindingParameter> BindingParameters{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy in the example. In fact, the project type is the correct public List <TmKeyValueItem> BindingParameters.